# JQuery Image Text/Caption Rollover

Tags: jquery, html, css, rollover

I need this rollover to show text when you hover over the image. I've looked up several different tutorials, but I can't find many about adding text/captions with jQuery. Lots with using CSS3, but none with just jQuery. I've tried the following:

**jQuery**

```
//We are using $(window).load here because we want to wait until the images are loaded
$(window).load(function(){
    //for each description div...
    $('div.description').each(function(){
        //...set the opacity to 0...
        $(this).css('opacity', 0);
        //..set width same as the image...
        $(this).css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());
        //...get the parent (the wrapper) and set it's width same as the image width... '
        $(this).parent().css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());
        //...set the display to block
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('div.wrapper').hover(function(){
        //when mouse hover over the wrapper div
        //get its children elements with class description '
        //and show it using fadeTo
        $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    },function(){
        //when mouse out of the wrapper div
        //use fadeTo to hide the div
        $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
    });

});
```

... with the following HTML...

**HTML**

```
<table id="intro"> 
    <tr>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <td>
                <a href="headwear.html"><img src="images/headwear.png" alt="headwear" /></a>
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="description_content">
                        This is just a test.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="apparel.html"><img src="images/apparel.png" alt="apparel" /></a>
                <a href="accessories.html"><img src="images/accessories.png" alt="accessories" /></a>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

... and these are the styles...

**CSS**

```
div.description{
    position: absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
    bottom: 0px; /* position will be on bottom */
    left: 0px;
    display: none; /* hide it */
    /* styling below */
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}
div.description_content{
    padding: 10px;
}

div.wrapper{
    position: relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */
}
#intro {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 1100px;
}
#intro img {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yutikohercell/brxu8w8m/

**Live**

http://jsfiddle.net/yutikohercell/brxu8w8m/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also remove `display:none` from css for `div.description` and add `opacity : 0`. `FadeTo` only changes the opacity, doesn't change the display as `block`.

```
$('img').hover(function() {
     $(this).closest('a').siblings('.description').fadeTo(500, 0.7); // finds the parent 'a' of the clicked element and then finds its sibling with the class 'description'.
  }, function() {
     $(this).closest('a').siblings('.description').fadeTo(500, 0);
  });
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/brxu8w8m/1/

Comment: I'm still not getting this to work at all. I removed the display:none and changed it, but it's not working as it should.

Comment: Check the fiddle for the entire logic